# Android Arabic/Farsi Fonts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fonts

I  am developing an Android aap that uses Arabic Fonts.
I have successfully display Arabic text by using **"tahoma.ttf"**
But **problem is that these Arabic Fonts Didn't give a cool look.**
So i wanted to change that Font Style. Is there any way of doing this ?

Comment: Do you want to change your font?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use external font do :

1. First step is to pick a font that you want to use.
2. Create a `fonts` folder in your assets directory and copy your font there.
3. To access your custom font,use the `Typeface` class in the Android SDK to create a typeface that Android can use, then set any display elements that need to use your custom font appropriately.

Unfortunately, you can no longer use layout XML for this, since the XML does not know about any fonts you may have tucked away as an application asset.You can do like this in your code:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/BPreplay.otf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

**Note**: Android does not seem to like all TrueType fonts.So, if you try to use a different font and it does not seem to be working, it may be that the font is incompatible with Android, for whatever reason.

You can see more details in these pages:
[Fun with Fonts](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/08/18/fun-with-fonts/)
[Musings of the Bare Bones Coder/using custom fonts](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/)